# Ember Loading Template never displaying

Tags: ember.js

I have tried

```
/app/routes/loading.hbs
/app/pods/loading/template.hbs
/app/pods/loading.hbs
/app/pods/application/loading/template.hbs
/app/pods/application/loading.hbs
/app/templates/loading.hbs
/app/templates/application-loading.hbs
```

None of the above work.

I added this to my application route and it works, but it is only rendering the spinner in the application template, not the appropriate outlet of the current route.

```
  //app/pods/application/template.hbs
  {{#if isLoading}}
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x"></i>
  {{/if}}

  //app/pods/application/route.js
  actions: {
    loading(transition, originRoute) {
      let controller = this.controllerFor('application');
      controller.set('isLoading', true);
      transition.promise.finally(function() {
        controller.set('isLoading', false);
      });
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why are the templates not rendering?  I am using ember-cli@2.4.2 with ember@2.4.1.

Comment: Maybe you're overwriting the default behaviour of Ember.Route "loading". Try this._super(...arguments)

Comment: Where do you want me to put this? It was not working even before I added the loading action.  I only used it as a workaround.

Comment: Mkae, then this is not the problem. Thought it broke as you added the loading action.

Answer (score 3):

Been struggling on this as well, Patrick's answer helped a lot but calling super according to that thread didn't help either. Removing the loading action did help, but the root cause is actually not because of having the loading action. You can keep the loading action but in order to have the loading template render you need to `return true;` from the loading action, if you don't return true then the loading template will not be rendered.

My guess is that if you don't return true the event stops propagating which prevents the default behaviour from happening

Answer (score 2):

If you look at docs more carefully then you will see

[image]

It implies that you need to add

```
/app/pods/application-loading/template.hbs
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this problem for two days. I'm using Ember 2.5.0 and a pod structure. My loading template is located in app/templates/loading.hbs. Diving deeper into it led me to ember-resolver and [this issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-resolver/issues/103). If you get rid of the loading action, it will show the loading template - very strange. The thread says to call super if you need to catch the event but that has not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
/app/templates/loading.hbs
```

without using the loading action?

The loading action stops the propagation of the loading event, unless you return true from the action.

Comment: Yes, second from the bottom.

Comment: I will try this again though.

Comment: I was not sure if you also tried without having the loading action defined, because your question didn't make that clear

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to overwrite the loading-action in the route. Just define a app/templates/loading.hbs. Whenever you load a model from any route, the loading template will shown automatically. 
if you want to use a attribute to show a loading state you shoud make an loading-service, which you can then access in every route, controller or component.

EDIT: You should also read the guide: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

If you follow the guide you shoud see how the loading-template works.